# I am trying fcm to send message to other app using retrofit class but it gives error in retrofit class

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, retrofit2

**That is the error i am getting whenever i try to initialize the fcm class object**

```
com.example.myfoodserver E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myfoodserver, PID: 28042
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:263)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:229)
        at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:202)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.build(Retrofit.java:628)
        at com.example.myfoodserver.remote.RetrofitFCMClient.getInstance(RetrofitFCMClient.java:17)
        at com.example.myfoodserver.ui.order.OrderFragment.initViews(OrderFragment.java:126)
        at com.example.myfoodserver.ui.order.OrderFragment.onCreateView(OrderFragment.java:106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
```

***This is the fcm class code***

```
public interface IFCMService {
    @Headers({"Authorization: key=AAAAVY7Xgs4:APA91bF_OPZaLVUixFZ3yxBG2lJn2s45o1J99cvO2YW-gBOGbpUkeUUDgalJsiTuTMXBA1orPa2Uqjt1Gsd_FcbOdoMpjy7VZzwfZPzV_YKDWCXBeu",
            "Content-Type:application/json"})
    @POST("fcm/send")
    Observable<FCMResponse> sendNotification(@Body FCMSendData body);
```

*This is retrofit class which gives error on build line*

```
public class RetrofitFCMClient {
    private static Retrofit instance;

    public static Retrofit getInstance() {

        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        return instance;

    }
}
```

[This is the ScreenShot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYSlc.png)

Comment: ifcmService = RetrofitFCMClient.getInstance().create(IFCMService.class);

Comment: that is where i initialize the object of fcm class which gives error, i am still not getting why when i try to initialize the retrofit object it gives this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to happen due to the fact that okhttp dropped support for android versions below 5 in release 3.13+
See https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4481
A solution would be to enforce an older okhttp version by adding/changing your dependencies to

```
implementation ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp'){
    version {
        strictly '3.12.12'
    }
}
```

On a side note, next time you upload your code, make sure to remove api keys and such

Comment: that did'nt work and don't worry about api key it is fake one it is just for the reference to show i put key not leave it empty. Thanks for your concern and error is same as i mentioned earlier

Comment: I think you are right but could you show me how to add okhttp client to resolve this because my app support lower than 21 api and i think the issue i face is because okhttp drop support for lower api than 21 and need a client to intercept

Comment: @AliHamza I updated my answer, check if this works for you

Comment: how is this related to androidx? these are 2 complete different things

Comment: Sorry my mistake now i am able to finish it. I just need to do some research on this syntax now i get it